# Unity facebook simulator build for review

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, vuforia, prime31

I am trying to upload a simulator build for review on facebook. But unfortunately this is impossible with unity3d including prime31 and vuforia. Apparently there is something in their library that doesn't allow simulator builds. So is there any other way to send my build to the review team? Because I really need to upload my app in a few days!
I am using the latest unity 4.6.2, the latest vuforia 3.0.9 and prime31 Etcetera Android and ios.

Thanks.

Comment: Facebook says: Mobile apps developed with Unity should upload a dummy build and include a screencast of the integration.

what is a dummy build and where can I upload it?

Comment: did you find a solution? And what about "dummy build"?